# Does if condition/ for loop makes a new variable scope in java?

Tags: java, scope, variable-assignment

I got a question like this:

Consider the following Java program

```
class main_class
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int x = 9;
        if (x == 9)
        {
            int x = 8;
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

A.9
B.8
C.Compilation Error
D.Runtime Error

I chose B, but I operated in my local environemnt and I find I'm wrong, the duplicated variable is not allowed in if condition. But what I thought is I always use for(int i=0;i<len;i++) when I'm coding, but the "i" is not duplicated, doesn't "{}" means a new variable scope? it makes me a little confused.

The local operation is conducted as below on my VS code env
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10qaM.png)

Comment: In your loop example the ‘I’ is only declared once. ‘for(int i=0;i<len;i++){ int i = 3; System.out.println(i);’ would not be valid code.

Comment: When you post code, *always* use text rather than images. It's fine to include a screenshot as well (although with a better description than "enter image description here") - but the code itself should be in the question as text. Without opening the screenshot, your point about `for` loops is really unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each block is a new scope in Java - *but* as per [JLS 6.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4):

> It is a compile-time error if the name of a local variable `v` is used to declare a new variable within the scope of `v`, unless the new variable is declared within a class or interface declaration appearing within the scope of `v`.

So it's fine to have a *field* called `v` and then declare a local variable called `v`, but you can't declare nest two local variable declarations of `v` (aside from local class declarations etc).

In your other code of:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
}
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
}
```

... the scope of each `i` variable is the `for` loop itself. As per [JLS 6.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) :

> The scope of a local variable declared in the ForInit part of a basic for statement (§14.14.1) includes all of the following:
>
> - Its own initializer
> - Any further declarators to the right in the ForInit part of the for statement
> - The Expression and ForUpdate parts of the for statement
> - The contained Statement

So it's similar to writing:

```java
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    }
}
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    }
}
```

... clearly there's no nesting of the declarations of `i`. Neither variable is declared within the scope of the other.

Comment: thanks, your rewriting makes me more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You also may be confusing the following two examples.

```
class main_class
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int x = 9;
        { 
            // x still in scope during second re-declaration.
            int x = 10; // compilation issue other x still in this scope
        }
// vs
        {
            int y = 9;
        }
        int y = 10; // OK. Second declaration fine since scope is not shared.
                    // first y goes out of scope prior to second declaration.
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I tried your example, it makes me confused, just the declaration order difference makes different,I can't understand why it happens.  As I often declare variable first,maybe I will check it out some day, and just hope that can't  be an question in exam. haha

Answer (score 0):

There is this concept of variable scope in Java.
More details to your question here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271683/why-can-we-use-the-same-name-for-local-variable-in-different-scopes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).